# Why is the Generator Point G for secp256k1 curve typically indicated in (y,-x) quadrant?

Tags: security, private-key, public-key, secp256k1

Generator Point G for the secp256k1 curve is typically indicated below where the curve intersects the y-axis. At x=0, y=sqrt(7) and -sqrt(7), which are both small numbers less than 3, but G is an extremely large integer.

If it falls on the curve below the y-axis crossing it would have to have an x-coord of < 2 and y-coord of < 3 (or less than [2,3] above the %P). Is this the case or have I got something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: I don't know which "typically" you're talking about, but I've tried answering a misunderstanding you may have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secp256k1 curve is defined by the equation *y<sup>2</sup> = x<sup>3</sup> + 7* with coordinates X and Y over the field *GF(p)* with *p=2<sup>256</sup> - 2<sup>32</sup> - 977*, not the field of real numbers. This field consists of the integers modulo *p*. In this field, there is no concept of "smaller" or "larger", no concept of "decimals", and no concept of "positive" or "negative". For example, the numbers *-1* and *115,792,089,237,316,195,423,570,985,008,687,907,853,269,984,665,640,564,039,457,584,007,908,834,671,662* represent the same field element. One is small, the other is large; one is negative, the other is positive.

Furthermore, the modulo effect applies for *all* arithmetic operations. For addition, subtraction, and multiplication, it just means reducing modulo *p* after performing normal addition, subtraction, or multiplication. But that's not all. Division is the reverse operation of multiplication, so *a/b mod p* is really asking "what value of *x* in the field satisfies *a = bx mod p*?" which is a very different thing from division in the reals. Similarly, a square root is the reverse operation of squaring, so *√a* is really asking "what value of *x* in the field satisfies *a = x<sup>2</sup> mod p*?".

*7* has no square roots in this field. That is, there exists no integer *x* such that *x<sup>2</sup> mod p = 7*. Thus, there is no point on the secp256k1 curve with X coordinate *0*. *1<sup>3</sup> + 7 = 8* does have a square root (namely, *29,896,722,852,569,046,015,560,700,294,576,055,776,214,335,159,245,303,116,488,692,907,525,646,231,534*) so in principle it would have been possible to choose G to have X coordinate 1. It's not known how the X and Y coordinate of G were chosen however, but presumably an X coordinate was picked for which *x<sup>3</sup> + 7* does have a square root *mod p*, and then one of these square roots was chosen as the Y coordinate.

More reading:

- [What does the curve used in Bitcoin, secp256k1, look like?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/21911/208)
- [How is the generator point G chosen in the secp256k1 curve used in Bitcoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/113122/208)

Comment: Thanks Pieter, I understand some parts of this but not others... when you say {1^3 + 7 = 8 [x^2]} does have a square root mod p, does it mean that there is an integer value x which, when squared then divided by p, gives a remainder of 8?

Comment: @b0d That's exactly right.