# Is it possible to use bitcoin-cli deriveaddress rpc call to generate ethereum address?

Tags: bitcoin-cli, ethereum

https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0044.md
As per this slip, if we just change the cointype in the descriptor, the deriveaddress rpc call should work to generate ethereum addresses from an xpub too. But it isn't? I can not find any good documentation on this rpc call whether it supports all the bip standards in the derivation path or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Bitcoin addresses and Ethereum addresses are constructed and defined differently and bitcoin-cli certainly does not support Ethereum address generation. For more details on why see this [question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/114625/is-the-g-in-elliptical-curve-same-for-bitcoin-and-ethereum).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Cleared some of my doubts.